# Python - Removing a node from a linked-list at beginning, in between and at end

Tags: python, nodes

I learned about linked-lists today. I learned how to insert and remove nodes from them. In the following code, it teaches me how to insert nodes with three distinct functions: at beginning (the head node), in between and at the end. However, they teach me how to remove the node in and single function. I don't find the code in the remove function to be very clear. Can anyone help make an easier to understand code under the remove function? Is there a way to make it into three functions just like the inserting ones? I'm open to any suggestion or explanation. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextnode = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headnode = None

    def printlist(self):
        node = self.headnode
        while node is not None:
            print (node.data)
            node = node.nextnode

    def atbegining(self,new_node):
        new_node.nextnode = self.headnode
        self.headnode = new_node

    # Function to add newnode
    def AtEnd(self, newnode):
        if self.headnode is None:
            self.headnode = newnode
            return
        node = self.headnode
        while(node.nextnode):
            node = node.nextnode
        node.nextnode=newnode

    # Function to add node
    def Inbetween(self,preNode,newNode):
        if preNode is None:
            print("The mentioned node is absent")
            return
        newNode.nextnode = preNode.nextnode
        preNode.nextnode = newNode

    # Function to remove node
    def RemoveNode(self, RemoveVal):

        node = self.headnode

        if (node is not None):
            if (node.data == RemoveVal):
                self.headnode = node.nextnode
                node = None
                return

        while (node is not None):
            if node.data == RemoveVal:
                break
            prevnode = node
            node = node.nextnode

        if (node == None):
            return

        prevnode.nextnode = node.nextnode

        node = None


list1 = LinkedList()
list1.headnode = Node("Mon")
n2 = Node("Tue")
n3 = Node("Wed")
# Link first Node to second node
list1.headnode.nextnode = n2
# Link second Node to third node
n2.nextnode = n3
n4 = Node("Sun")
n5 = Node("Tur")
n6 = Node("Newdate")

list1.atbegining(n4)
list1.AtEnd(n5)

list1.Inbetween(list1.headnode,n6)
list1.RemoveNode("Newdate")
list1.printlist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RemoveNode` is complicated by the fact that there are two structurally distinct kinds of `LinkedList`s: one whose head is `None`, and one whose head is not `None`. You can fix this by making sure every `LinkedList` contains at least one node. This is typically referred to as a dummy node, and you can use this node to store metadata (such as the length of the list).

The `Node` class itself does not change.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextnode = None
```

The `LinkedList`, however, simplifies by creating a dummy node. This provides
the guarantee that every node that stores real data is point to by another node.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headnode = Node(0)

    def insert(self, preNode, newNode):
        newNode.nextnode = preNode.nextnode
        preNode.nextnode = newNode
        self.headnode.data += 1

    def append(self, newNode):
        curr = self.headnode
        while curr.nextNode is not None:
            curr = curr.nextNode

        self.insert(curr, newNode)

    def prepend(self, newNode):
        self.insert(self.headnode, newNode)

    def _find_before(self, val):
        pre = self.headnode
        while pre.nextnode is not None:
            curr = pre.nextnode
            if curr.data == val:
                return pre
            pre = curr

    def remove(self, RemoveVal):
        pre = self._find_before(RemoveVal)
        if pre is None:
            return
        pre.nextnode = pre.nextnode.nextnode
        self.headnode.data -= 1
```

This simplifies all three insertions. The general case can always apply, since there is always a node that comes before the node you insert. `append` and `prepend` are simple wrappers that find the appropriate node to pass to `insert`.
Likewise, `remove` simply finds the node *before* the given value, and if the search succeeds, handles updating the prior node's `nextnode` attribute.

`insert` and `remove` also update the size of the list stored in the dummy node.

A `find` method becomes a simple wrapper around `_find_before`; if you find a node before the value you are looking for, just return the node that follows it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that an alternative design will make the code much clearer. Consider for example the following:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextnode = None

    def printlist(self):
        print(self.data)
        if self.nextnode is not None:
            self.nextnode.printlist()

    def push(self, node):
        node.nextnode = self
        return node

    def insertafter(self, node):
        node.nextnode = self.nextnode
        self.nextnode = node
        return self

    def append(self, node):
        lastnode = self
        while lastnode.nextnode is not None:
            lastnode = lastnode.nextnode

        lastnode.nextnode = node
        return self

    def remove(self, value):
        prev = None
        walk = self

        while walk is not None:
            if walk.data == value:
                if prev is None:
                    return walk.nextnode
                else:
                    prev.nextnode = walk.nextnode
                    return self
            else:
                prev = walk
                walk = walk.nextnode

        return self

list1 = Node("Mon")
n2 = Node("Tue")
n3 = Node("Wed")
# Link first Node to second node
list1 = list1.insertafter(n2)
# Link second Node to third node
n2 = n2.insertafter(n3)
n4 = Node("Sun")
n5 = Node("Tur")
n6 = Node("Newdate")

list1 = list1.push(n4)
list1 = list1.append(n5)

list1 = list1.insertafter(n6)
list1 = list1.remove("Newdate")
list1.printlist()
```

The main idea is that a `Node` is the linked list. As long as you have the head of the list kept in a variable, you can have access to the entire list, without the need for a separate data structure.